# Equivalent for \hookrightarrow, ↪

Tags: symbols, character-encoding, named-characters

Of course I can simply type the unicode ↪, but is there a operator with no built in meaning that renders like this?

The documentation guide/ArrowsAndArrowLikeForms presumably lists all arrows.  If it doesn't exist, can I define Output and typesettings rules for the unicode character?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. This character does not have any built-in meaning and can be [used as a symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbpNa.png) with no apparent problems. What _exactly_ are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use an empty [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox) to create a new operator. For example:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[],{InputAutoReplacements,"ha"}] = TemplateBox[
    {},
    "HookRightArrow",
    DisplayFunction -> Function@"↪",
    InterpretationFunction :> Function[Sequence["~", "HookRightArrow", "~"]]
];
```

Then, typing <kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>space</kbd> <kbd>h</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>space</kbd> <kbd>y</kbd> produces:

[image: x Sequence["~", "HookRightArrow", "~"] y]

and when evaluated yields:

> HookRightArrow[x, y]

Comment: Very neat.  I was familiar with defining `InputAutoReplacements`, but having it resolve to the symbol is very nice.